# A small emacs-lisp snippet for opening a register in another window

Tags: lisp, elisp, emacs

I'd like to get some feedback on whether this is idiomatic elisp, whether it's any good, and any small modifications that would be useful.  Thanks

```
(defun jump-to-register-other-window (register-name)
  "Open a register in the other window if file"
  ;; Should also display register contents if register is text
  ;; jump-to-register allows it to fail silently if non-legit
  ;; register is passed in

  (interactive "cJump to register: \n")
  (let ((cur-buff (buffer-name)))
    (jump-to-register register-name)
    (let ((register-buffer (buffer-name)))
      (switch-to-buffer cur-buff)
      (switch-to-buffer-other-window register-buffer))))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x 4 j") 'jump-to-register-other-window)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first things which jump into my face are the broken indentation and a dangling parenthesis. Please fix them, otherwise the code is not very readable.

More to the point, I think it is better to replace the body with

```
(switch-to-buffer-other-window (register-buffer register-name))
```

and define

```
(defun register-buffer (register-name)
  (save-window-excursion 
    (jump-to-register register-name)
    (current-buffer)))
```

Comment: I fixed the indentation and dangling bracket (I think, perhaps I've missed something). Thanks for `save-excursion` - I think that's what I was looking for.

Comment: `save-excursion` does not restore the buffer to the window it was in though (from  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Excursions.html)

Comment: Edited to use `save-window-excursion` instead, thanks!